# Divisibility of Fibonacci Sequence mod prime

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

I have to solve the following problem and I have a few questions: 
Consider the Fibonacci sequence defined as $F_n:=2F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ with $F_0=1$ and $F_1=1$. Now, I need to prove that for any odd prime p $$F_p=(5/p) \mod p $$. 
My first question is, why is the fibonacci sequence defined with a $2$ multiplying $F_{n-1}$, and I don't really know how to prove this. I tried using Gauss´s Quadratic Reciprocity, but I can´t reach the conclusion I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "$(5/p)modp$"?

Comment: If they are using $2$ in the recurrence then this is not the Fibonacci sequence, and calling the $n$-th term $F_n$ makes ir worse. You might compute to find out whether the relationship appears to be true. I get $F_3=7$, which is congruent to $1$ mod $3$, while $(5/3)=-1$.  It is hard to guess what typo(s) may have been made.